# Mechanize form nr=0 error

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to automate login to webpage using python mechanize but getting error. Using below code:

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open('http://server:7180/cmf/home')
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form['j_username'] = 'nathalok'
browser.form['j_password'] = '******'
browser.submit()
response = browser.open('http://server:7180/cmf/allHealthIssues')
print response.read()
```

But i get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mechanizetest.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser.select_form(nr=0)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0
```

I could see the below source code for the webpage:

```
<form class="LoginForm well" action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label for="username"><i class="glyphicon tiny user"></i> Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-large" id="username" name="j_username" autofocus />
        <label for="password"><i class="glyphicon tiny lock"></i> Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="input-large" id="password" name="j_password" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" value=""/>


            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" />&nbsp; Remember me on this computer.</label>

        <hr/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" name="submit">Login</button>
    </form><!-- LoginForm -->
```

Appreciate any help as how to automate login or resolve this error.

Comment: Does the page you are reading loads after a short while? (aka dinamically generated?)

Comment: Yes, the page is dynamically generated

Comment: Then it is possible that the source your script is getting is not the one that you see in the browser. I recommend using [Selenium and use a wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) to deal with the page loading.

Comment: Is Selenium the only option here? Can you not bake in a delay with mechanize? What if you can see the `<form>` tag in the `br.response().read()` output?